# How do you move an SVG around a webpage without triggering slow redraws?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to draw a (multi)line graph (with quite a few data-points, 1600 to be exact) on an svg element.
This graph is in a container which has a transition on it.

On a certain event the container gets moved 400px to the top with a CSS3 transition which works fine in Chrome. When trying in Safari and Firefox I noticed that is was really slow. After some checks I can say with 99% certainty that the svg element gets redrawn during the transition (a lot) in Safari/Firefox (and possible other browsers, too).

Is there anyway to prevent the browser redrawing it constantly until the transition is finished? Or maybe other solutions that would make this fluent?

FYI: not drawing the chart in the SVG element makes the issue go away, so I'm certain the slowdown comes from the SVG element.

The simplified html code:

```
<div id="container" style="transition:margin 0.75s; -webkit-transition:margin 0.75s; ">
    <svg id="simple_line" style='height:210px; width:100%;'/>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the element to transition, it has to be redrawn at the intermediate positions.

Comment: Makes sense... In the mean time i added js to hide the graph during the transition and show it when it is done (css: display:none;), this makes the transition go smooth again (because the element is not drawn by the browser until the very end). This is not an ideal solution so if there are still better ideas, they would be welcome

Comment: You could just remove the transition.

Comment: Shure ;) that would make it perfectly smooth, but designers... ;)

Comment: If all you want is the delay in it appearing at the other position, you could use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Generally speaking, using *margin* or any other CSS position value to make objects move around the screen is sub-optimum.  Try using a transform/translation to create the movement, which will tell the browser to use graphical optimization methods.

Comment: AmeliaBR, thank you! I'll try that tomorrow, what kind of performance enhancement do you think this could make? A significant (visible) one, or is this more of a 'best-practise' kind of thing?

Comment: @Gregory I haven't done any testing myself, I would be interested in your results.  The idea is that a transform tells the browser to move around a block of rendered content, instead of re-calculating the whole layout.  But it will still depend on the quality of the browser's implementation...

Comment: @AmeliaBR: the difference is significant! Even without first hiding the graph, the transition is super smooth. Thank you for this

Comment: Hi @Gregory.  Glad you got it working.  So this doesn't continue to show up as unanswered, I'm going to edit your question to focus on your original problem (lagging performance when moving) and then re-post the above comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, using `margin` or any other CSS position value to make objects move around the screen is sub-optimum. Try using a [transform/translation style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to create the movement, which will tell the browser to use graphical optimization methods.

The idea is that a transform tells the browser to move around a block of rendered content, instead of re-calculating the whole layout. Results will still depend on the quality of the browser's implementation -- as you discovered, Chrome has good optimization either way, but this should reduce the browser-to-browser differences.